# Can not able to serve media files on cpanel django

Tags: django, cpanel, production, whitenoise

I build a website with Django and now hosting it. I used Whitenoise to serve images but only static ones shows up when debug is False. How can I serve media files uploaded by users too? Since it is my first development with Django detailed help would be much appreciated kind folk of the Stack.

Comment: Seems like WhiteNoise themselves declares that it is not suitable for serving user-uploaded “media” files. [link](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html#serving-media-files)

Answer (score 2):

I reached my host provider's support and thanks to them I saw it was not that hard. Since I am using a shared host they was conigured serving files defult with CloudLinux. All I have to do is take static and media files on **public_html** folder. And change the media root for here because I want users uploaded images to get here too. To sum up solution is public_html folder.